# Error accessing Xpage using $$OpenDominoDocument.xsp method on database replica

Tags: xpages, database-replication, opendocument

I have a Form called 'Contact Level\Customer Contact | Customer Contact', which is a response document, and in the properties I have associated the customerContact XPage to the form. In all view panel controls I have use the 'XPage associated with the document's form' property.

On server A the XPage is opened correctly using the $$OpenDominoDocument.xsp method from any view control.

On server B, which has a replica of the server A database, the XPage does not open from any of the views using the $$OpenDocumentDocument.xsp method. The error I see on the server log is 'HTTP Web Server: Item Not Found Exception [db.nsf/$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp?documentId=......&action=openDocument]'.

I have removed sections of code from the XPage to track down whereabouts the error is happening and it was the domino document settings that cause the problem.

I have checked the form properties and they are correct.

If I change the $$OpenDominoDocument.xsp section of the URL to customerContact.xsp then the document opens without error.

If I change the view panel property to explicitly open the customerContact XPage then again the document opens without error.

I have tried changing the form and XPage so it opens the 'contact' XPage instead (an almost identical non-response version of the same form) and the XPage still errored.

I tried saving a document in client but the XPage still errored.

I changed the form name to include a new alias of CustomerContact and modified a document to use the new form name, and this document opened without error. That made me wonder if the space in the Customer Contact name was causing the error, but there are many forms / XPages on the database in question, some others with spaces in there alias, and this is the only form that errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a different server version number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there another Form or Subform that has the same name or has "Customer Contact" as an alias? I have a feeling I read a blog some time ago that mentioned $$OpenDocument picking up a subform instead of a form, but I'm not 100% sure, so that may be wrong. If it's working on a newer server, that issue may have been fixed.

Comment: Hi Paul, there was a Web only form with the same alias that did not have the XPage associated to it. I've now updated that form and it is working on the replica. Many thanks!